# Copied scene needs a user?

Tags: python, scene, data-blocks

From the default startup, if you run
`bpy.context.scene.copy()`
you get a copy of your scene that has 0 user and gets added to the orphan data.

In reality, if you save and revert the file, your scene will still be there, even though any other orphan data would get removed if you did that.
However, for the users of my add-on, seeing an orphan scene would be confusing and worrying.

I could add a fake user but I find it unsatisfactory and still confusing, as you may wonder what would happen when trying to delete the scene, not to mention the unnecessary "F" in the scene's name.

So how can I make that scene not orphan without adding a fake user?

So far the only hacky workaround I found is to run some operator and then run the undo operator, which I assume does the trick because it reloads many components of the file including the scene's user (whatever it is), but of course this is far from an ideal solution.

Comment: As with all ID objects `ob.use_fake_user = True` prevents a zero user count.

Comment: Sorry, when editing my post I accidentally deleted the line where I talk about not using a fake user, silly me! It's back now.

Answer (score 2):

**Use the operator**

For the time being whilst using `Scene.copy()` produces a zero user scene, using the operator instead, does not

```
bpy.ops.scene.new(type='FULL_COPY')
```

A new scene created via `newscene = scene.copy()` does not pick up  the window using it (as a user) when `context.window.scene = newscene` nor does the one being unset lose a user.   I imagine this will be fixed sometime soon.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use the operator for several reasons (performance, context and naming issues). Using copy() is way simpler and faster so I'll just leave the scenes with zero user and give a warning that this doesn't mean the scene will be deleted.
I hope this will get fixed. Should I make a report on developer.blender.org?